# What noise would it be timing chain ?? Why

Tags: noise, vauxhall, timing-chain

Car: Vauxhall Corsa D 2012 sxi.

Engine: A14XER

Video link of the issue: https://youtu.be/V1cyy1oL_Hg

Is the noise you hear at around 6 7 seconds mark and again around 10 12 seconds mark in in the video my timing chain noise ??
The noise is definitely coming from the driver's side where the timing chain is as well. The noise goes away after a few minutes of driving and only occurs during cold start.

If it is then why, since I replaced the timing chain, the bottom small sprocket on the crankshaft, timing cover gasket, timing chain tensioner and the chain guides just two weeks ago.

**A backstory though**, A year ago I had the cylinder head skimmed because my car had a tiny warped head which was drinking coolant at an alarming rate. After the cylinder head skim job everything fit flush and was working fine until about 6 months ago, I started to hear similar timing chain noise but I left it until 2 weeks ago where I opened up the timing cover to investigate what was happening, thinking that some screws for the tensioner or chain guides might have come loose, but everything was fine but I replaced those parts anyway with brand new ones because I pre ordered them and I made damn sure that everything is tight but still I hear those noise for a few minutes during first start of the day.
There is no oil/fluid leaks and oil pressure is also fine.

Would the head skim have cause the timing chain to have a tiny slack since the skim decreased its height (Im not sure how much material they skimmed though), though everything fit flush when re assembling. Also when I released the pin on the tensioner the chain was rock solid tight
so would greatly appreciate if anyone could have some guesses or ideas as to what is causing that noise at cold starts. Its really bothering me but the car runs totally fine, no dashboard error lights and the noise only occurs during the first few minutes of the drive then goes away for almost the day.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be the timing chain.  I'd check the tensioner at this point.